# CSP error when using Facebook Checkbox plugin as an iframe widget

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk, content-security-policy, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to build **a widget that other websites can include via an iframe**. The plugin contains the [Facebook Checkbox Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin/).

Consider the following code for the iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '3297885870227646',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v4.0'
    });
  };

</script>
<script async crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>


<body>
    <div class="fb-messenger-checkbox"
      origin="https://fb-marketing-widget.herokuapp.com/widget-iframe"
      page_id="110054573751247"
      messenger_app_id="3297885870227646"
      user_ref="<%= userRef %>"
      allow_login="true"
      size="standard"
      skin="light"
      center_align="true">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The above code works when opening the iframe URL directly in the browser**. However, **when I include the same iframe in another website with a different domain**, I'm getting Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/v4.0/plugins/messenger_checkbox.php?... in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://my-iframe-domain.com".

Please note that the iframe works when being opened directly, so this is clearly **not a problem with whitelisting the domain**, having the wrong app id etc.

Any input on how I can the above code as an iframe to be included in other websites would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. The name of that CSP directive is `frame-ancestors`, not just `frame-parent`. So if the Facebook iframe gets embedded on your domain A, that then itself gets framed by B again - then both A and B would have to be specified as valid frame ancestors. Although page admins can add up to 50 white-listed domains, I don’t see how you would get Facebook to respond with a `frame-ancestors` directive that contains both. They respond back with what corresponds to your specified `origin`, and I doubt that takes more than one URL somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook restricts which sites are able to frame their content, the error you see comes from your site not being allowed to frame the content from Facebook. Implementation step 1 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin/) for  Facebook Checkbox plugin is to whitelist your domain(s): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting. This is not something you can change on your page.